# qt qgraphicsWidget registered as qml type and plotting graph, but graph is not working smooth when after adding any animation

Tags: qt, plot, qml, qwt

first image shows correct (smooth) plotting graph. but when i add any animation like color change, opacity change or text change, graph fails. as you can see in second picture right of graph disappeared...

plot object inherited from qgraphicsproxywidget. registered as qmltype and plotting class inherited from qwtPlot

also did :

`QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("raster");
QDeclarativeView::setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);`

any ideas?

without animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMVSu.png
  with animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fhuc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: it depends on qml scene updating

so change your scene updating mode what you needs.

this solved my needs:

```
declarativeobject->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::SmartViewportUpdate);
```